# how i can bind sql query data with entity NotMapped property

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

if have entity model object with following code

```
  public class LeftMenu {

    [NotMapped]
    public bool HasChildExist { get; set; }

}
```

this class has many other properties
but when I try to fill above object with the following code my HasChildExist not reflecting proper record

```
 public IList<LeftMenu> GetRootNodes(string ID) {
        List<LeftMenu> list = null;

        String SQLQuery = ("Select * , [dbo].[HasChildExist](ID)  as  HasChildExist From dbo.LeftMenus where  ParentID is null");

        list = Context.Database.SqlQuery<LeftMenu>(SQLQuery).ToList();

        return list;
    }
```

I have scalar-valued function with named HasChildExist() that return bit value, this function embedded in SQL query you can see it in above query 
so my problem is when I run above method  my list  fills with all the returned records except HasChildExist value

Comment: Perhaps use a different class that doesn't have the `[NotMapped]` attribute in it?

Comment: no success when i remove NotMapped annotation of that property